I am building a YouTube Shorts clone using Next.js and Swiper but have encountered several issues
Videos are stored on firestorage and a mongo database.
Link Transition Issue: When the user clicks on a video link, the video is displayed as the first item in the slider. However, when scrolling to the second slide, the video moves to a different position and doesn't match the expected placement.
export function SwiperVideo({ videos }) {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { videoId } = router.query;

    const { fetchVideo, video } = useSubmitVideoData((state) => ({
        fetchVideo: state.fetchVideo,
        video: state.video,
    }));

    useEffect(() => {
        if (videos && videos.length > 0) {
            if (!videoId) {
                const initialVideoId = videos[0]?._id;
                if (initialVideoId) {
                    router.replace({
                        pathname: router.pathname,
                        query: { videoId: initialVideoId },
                    });
                    fetchVideo(initialVideoId);
                }
            } else {
                fetchVideo(videoId);
            }
        }
    }, [videos]);

    const handleSlideChange = (swiper) => {
        const activeVideoId = videos[swiper.activeIndex]._id;
        router.replace({
            pathname: router.pathname,
            query: { videoId: activeVideoId },
        });
        fetchVideo(activeVideoId);
    };

    return (
        <Swiper
            onSlideChange={handleSlideChange}
            direction="vertical"
            speed={800}
            pagination={{
                clickable: true,
            }}
            mousewheel={{
                thresholdDelta: 50,
                sensitivity: 1,
            }}
        >
            {videos?.map((item, index) => (
                <SwiperSlide key={index}>
                    <div>
                        <video
                            src={video?.url}
                            autoPlay
                            muted
                            key={video?._id}
                        />
                    </div>
                </SwiperSlide>
            ))}
        </Swiper>
    );
}


I’ve tried adjusting various Swiper settings, including lazy loading, but the issue persists.

I also attempted to switch the videos on the server side, but I’m not very experienced with backend development and am unsure how to proceed further.


